# Create a desktop application using PHP

Tags: php, web, cross-platform, desktop-application

I have a PHP/MySQL powered SaaS application which I want to deploy an offline version of. I don't want to use any of the numerous PHP GUI tools that are out there, as this would require rebuilding the GUI and I want it to look exactly the same as the web version.

I want to run Apache/MySQL servers (or something similar) on the clients' systems and somehow compile the PHP code so the source code isn't visible. What is the best way of doing this? Ideally I want to have one .exe file that would start/stop the server.

The following is a very similar question, but it is related to Python and not PHP: [Create application for web & desktop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10845428/create-application-for-web-desktop)

Comment: You might also look at https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/web2py/aVbouI7Dby8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can "hide" the source code by creating a compressed [phar archive](http://php.net/intro.phar).

As webserver you can use [PHP's built in webserver](http://php.net/features.commandline.webserver).

As an offline database, normally sqlite is fitting, if you need Mysql, there is [an embedded version of Mysql available](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/libmysqld.html) as well so you can embed that as well, probably through a PHP C extension.

Comment: To take it a step further, package your application with PHP Nightrain. So, you won't have to worry about the user installing PHP, Apache, etc... on his computer. Here's a quick youtube video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GXt8erPLf4o

Answer (score 1):

[TideSDK](http://www.tidesdk.org/) would be good option. They provide better support.

Answer (score 0):

[Server2go](http://www.server2go-web.de/) + [Ioncube](http://www.ioncube.com/) could be your best o

Answer (score 0):

There are some tools and technologies that can help in that. Check this list from sitepoint: [3 Ways to Develop Cross Platform Desktop Apps with PHP](http://www.sitepoint.com/3-ways-develop-cross-platform-desktop-apps-php/), and here is an example of application done with PHP: [Create your first Desktop Application with PHP and PHP Desktop](http://phpocean.com/tutorials/back-end/create-your-first-desktop-application-with-php-and-php-desktop/4)